# How to display Body type in Swagger (OAS3) for GET requests?

Tags: xml, spring-boot, swagger-ui, http-get, http-verbs

So i'm working on some APIs (`Spring Boot`)where I have both input and output of type `XML`. For documenting, I'm using Swagger (OpenAPI 3). Here is the controller:

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping(value = "v1/my-endpoint", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public class MyController{

    private final MyService myService;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<MyObject> myMethod(@RequestBody @Valid @NotNull MyObjectRequest request) {
       // ...
       return response;
    }
}
```

My problem is: The endpoint being of type `GET`, the swagger interface shows the input of type `JSON` (see picture):

[image: json body input]

If I change the HTTP verb to `PATCH`, `POST` etc, it's showing correctly (see picture).

[image]

So, how can I make the swagger UI see the body of type `application/xml` ?

**EDIT1**: The changes have to be in code. I shouldn't make any changes in `.yaml` or `.properties` file

**EDIT2**: When sending the request this way(request body as JSON), being a GET method, the swagger generates the request with query parameters (so something like `localhost:8080?param1=string&param2=string&param3=string`)

Comment: Use [produces](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces--) instead of consumes that is for POST/PUT.

Comment: Doesn't work. Used this both at controller and method level, nothing works

Comment: @RequestBody is for `@PostMapping`

Comment: Teoretically, you can have Body payload with `GET` method, but it seems that Swagger UI does not support this feature

Answer (score 1):

As noted on [this page](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/http-get-delete-request-body-guidelines/#aioseo-using-swagger---no-support) Swagger UI does not support Get-requests with a payload in the body.